# "Clap" and "applaud" for someone

Tags: prepositions, verb-usage

Which sentence is usable in English when you are going to clap your hands in order to show your approval for instance when you enjoy the performance of a football player:

> - The coach **clapped** for him.
> - The coach **applauded** for him.

I think both verbs are used improperly here. I would be thankful if you could suggest me the correct verb in the proper grammatical structure or a fix expression which customarily is used in this sense.

Comment: The first suggests the player wasn't capable of clapping himself & had someone else do it for him. The second is better, but colloquially, you can applaud or clap someone, it doesn't need the 'for'. Clap has in very recent times, gained the subordinate [& oft times unspoken…] 'golf' clap, which would be a negative connotation

Comment: on second thoughts - lose the 'for' in all cases; it makes it seem like they are incapable of clapping themselves

Comment: But whereas one can only clap and clapping by itself doesn't imply an approval or a sense of encouragement and whereas 'applaud' has an implication of approval, I guess "applaud somebody" is far more clearer than "clap" in this sentence. Though as you mentioned, both can be used and both are correct and e.g. a coach can "clap a player" or "applaud a player" with the same meaning. Did I get you well? :)

Comment: applaud conveys more sense of approval; it's used for theatre actors, sportsmen [including golfers]. Clapping is the act of banging the palms together to make a noise, applause is the accolade imparted by that action.

Comment: Flamenco dancers don't applaud.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Interesting. I agree that the second should read _The coach applauded him_ (no _for_), but the first reads fine as-is: _The coach clapped for him._

Comment: my 'always torture the sentence' brain adds 'because he couldn't do it for himself' - it just does, there's nothing I can do to stop it. It's not 'wrong' it just is, even if you have to push it, unintentionally ambiguous.

Comment: omg, my girlfriend just handed me a drink & said 'cheers' .. & I clapped… mind over matter...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The coach clapped for him" and "The coach applauded him" both sound natural to my (American) ear.  "The coach applauded for him" does not sound as natural to me, but is still understandable and grammatically correct.

Comment: Thank you very much Jasper' although using 'for' doesn't make the sentence incorrect, but I guess the most common way is the version without the preposition 'for'; right?:)

Comment: I agree with this. Also, I think _applauded_ is more readily used in a figurative sense. In other words, _The coach applauded him_ could imply physical clapping, or it might simply mean "voiced approval," particularly in a sentence like, _The coach applauded his team's efforts_. The dictionaries seem to back me on that (see [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/applaud), [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/applaud), e.g.).

Comment: My American ear agrees with Jasper's:  "clap for someone" or "applaud someone" sound like you are expressing approval. Also "applaud _for_" sounds like it should be followed by a duration: "The audience applauded for ten minutes straight after the beautiful performance.  "Clap someone" sounds like you hit them (e.g. "The coach clapped his star player _on the back_ as they walked into the locker room")

Comment: @Adam do you mean 'clap somebody' can have another connotation and therefore sometimes it can cause confusion for the hearer / reader and consequently it would better to use 'clap someone' to avoid misunderstanding?

Comment: @A-friend -- "Clap <someone>" means to slap them, but in a friendly way (or at least not in a mean way).  The meaning (of the verb) does not depend on whether you say "Clap someone" or "Clap somebody" or "Clap Fred".

Comment: not to my ear, it does mean 'make the banging-together of hands' noise, though you can add, 'on the back/ear' to change the meaning from two hands to one plus 'other aspect'

Comment: "applauding _for_ someone" is _not_ IMHO grammatically correct.  _Applauding_ is the act of giving praise/approval and it applies directly to the object of the sentence, e.g. "I applaud you".

Comment: @J.R. This usage is not actually figurative, *applause* has just come to be strongly associated with *clapping* in English. *Applaud* is related to *laud*, from Latin (e.g. "magna cum laude") and is a general term for expressing approval.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the idea that both "The coach clapped for him" and "The coach applauded him" sound natural, but I would observe that in America, we're most used to using those words without any object, so the best, and MOST natural (at least for me), would be to say something more like "When the coach saw him cross into the endzone, he stood up and clapped."  (or applauded)

Answer (score 0):

As an American, I would say that the coach clapped, but the coach applauded for the player.

Comment: Can we continue this subject in a chat room Faraz?

Answer (score 0):

I also think 'clap for him' sounds natural, because we can use the preposition 'for' with the word 'clap' as a noun, as in: 
 A big clap for John
 , so why not use it with 'clap' as verb also.

Answer (score -2):

Clap and applaud are transitive verbs, so it is grammatically wrong for one to say "The coach clapped for him and 
The coach applauded for him"

The correct sentences are;
The coach clapped him.
The coach applauded him.

Response from
Opolot Richard
Teacher of English language.